# Windows cmake cannot find memset or other standard functions

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cmake

I am compiling a collection of packages using cmake, often for which I write my own CMakeLists.txt. I have to compile them both using Visual Studio 9 2008 and Visual Studio 14 2015

For VS2015 compilation often completes without problems, but with VS2008 I frequently bump into the problem that cmake doesn't link to or include some standard msvc libraries (or msvc runtime libraries to be specific). As a result, it cannot find `memset()` if it is called by a module. One of these modules is glew, which has the following output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target glew
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/glew.dir/C_/Users/Daniel/OneDrive/src/glew-2.0.0/src/glew.c.obj
glew.c
[ 16%] Building RC object CMakeFiles/glew.dir/C_/Users/Daniel/OneDrive/src/glew-2.0.0/build/glew.rc.res
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[ 25%] Linking C shared library bin\glew32.dll
   Creating library lib\glew32.lib and object lib\glew32.exp
glew.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function glewContextInit
bin\glew32.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
LINK failed. with 1120
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\cmake.portable\tools\cmake-3.6.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I know I have to [include the libcmt.lib or msvcrt.lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.90).aspx) (+headers) to the project, but I have no idea how to. I found some leads [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_build_my_MSVC_application_with_a_static_runtime.3F) and [here](https://braintrekking.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/dll-hell-how-to-include-microsoft-redistributable-runtime-libraries-in-your-cmakecpack-project/) but none have lead me anywhere so far. 
Is there also a way I could do this when calling cmake from the command line (and thus without having to edit or patch the CMakeLists.txt files themselves)?
Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the linker -nodefaultlib option; this can be set in the IDE GUI at Linker / Input / Ignore All Default Libraries / No